# creating java/c++ projects in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-cdt, ubuntu-12.04

I just upgraded to ubuntu 12.04 64bit (with a clean install).
When I installed eclipse i can only create a general or CVS projects.
I installed build-essential, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-jdt, openjdk-7-jdk but still can only create these type of projects.
Also when going into the eclipse installed software section I can clearly see that CDT and java SDK are installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use eclipse on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit too and I do not have any problem in creating different projects (see screenshot).

[image: Eclipse projects]

However, I never use the repository version of eclipse, I always download the package from the [eclipse website](http://www.eclipse.org/). It's only a matter of extracting the archive and starting the eclipse executable.

Another tip, make sure you are using the right perspective for the projects you want to create (`window`->`open perspective`).
From the screenshot, you can see in the top right corner that the opened perspective is `Java`.

Comment: When downloaded from the eclipse website i can create the projects! but how can i make the downloaded eclipse my default? like typing eclipse from shell will open it, and also where should i locate it?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/144549/how-to-install-eclipse-in-ubuntu-12-04 i think this solved it with your help thanks!